# white space occur at bottom of screen when using phonegap's camera in ios7

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios7

In my application ( jquery & phonegap project), in iOS7, everytime, when camera is used, there is a blank white layer at bottom. This doesn't happen on Android devices. just happen in ios7.
ios6 is ok.

anyone knows or has similar experience?

Answer (score 1):

just copy and replace

```
  static int score = 0;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
// View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's    size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
// you can do so here.

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
    viewBounds.origin.y = 10;
    //viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
    if (score==0) {
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
        score=1;
    }
    self.webView.frame = viewBounds;


}

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just copy

static int score = 0;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
    viewBounds.origin.y = 10;
    //viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
    if (score==0) {
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
        score=1;
    }
    self.webView.frame = viewBounds;


}

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

}